# Possible to add extra data to the HTML5 doctype

Tags: javascript, html, dom, doctype

Let's say that you're using a series of IE conditional comment tags at the top of your HTML document:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><html class="no-js ie6" lang="en" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie7" lang="en" ><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie8" lang="en" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js ie9" lang="en" ><!--<![endif]-->
```

And you want to add an extra piece of data to your page, but you don't want to populate each specific HTML element with redundant data. Is it possible to add an attribute or something to the doctype that you can refer to from your JS code? If you customize your doctype with custom code and if you do that then would it break the layout/view/rendering of your page?

--- EDIT ---

There may be better ways to deal with this without using conditional comments, but I'm more interested to see if the doctype can be hacked without breaking the page.

Comment: Protip: Don't use conditional comments like that. Detect features, not browsers.

Comment: @meagar non-IE browsers interpret all lines as comments, except the last one, which will become the <html> opening tag

Comment: Except that the second line it' wrong...

Comment: @meagar: infact, IE's conditional comments are only interpreted by IE, other browsers only understand the opening and closing comment on each line, and so interpret each line as comment. The <!--> and 
<!-- on last line are present to make them read the html tag. On second line they must not be present

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right again. I was misinterpreting my experiment; I thought that I'd been able to produce output in chrome with `<!--[if !IE]>` but really I had inputted a syntax error. My head is really not in the game today :|

Comment: Code is fixed. The purpose is not to know what's the right way to do it, but if you can hack the doctype without breaking the page.

Comment: ehm, @matsko, I understand, but you now lack a closed comment on last line (see my edit). Anyway, no it's not possible to add attributes on doctype tag. I think you can get the same result using the `body` tag

Comment: @matsko - Theoretically you could do it. But don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes to the `body` tag:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><html class="no-js ie6" lang="en" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie7" lang="en" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie8" lang="en" ><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js ie9" lang="en" ><!--<![endif]-->

<body class="custom-page">
</body>

...
```

This allow ,e.g. to filter tags this way: `$(".custom-page ul")`

Beware: I changed the second line, otherwise all browsers except IE will get two opening html tag.

Regarding the customization of the doctype, [html5 specifications](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype) are a bit strict on how you can write it, so no, you cannot add custom attributes in doctype.

Anyway, you can access the content doctype from javascript using `document.doctype`.
Trying the command in the console of this page return me `<!DOCTYPE html>`